# Does CookieUtil.SetEncryptedCookie work when load balancing?

Tags: cookies, azure, web-config, azure-web-roles

I'm migrating a .NET application to Azure with two web-servers in a load balancing configuration. Currently when users login to the application we set a cookie to store their company name as such.

```
CookieUtil.SetEncryptedCookie("CONAME", companyName);
```

My question is will these cookies persist across the two web servers? Without further configuration being applied? Does .NET use a machine key to encrypt the cookies as it does with forms authentication? If this is the case do we need to set this in the web.config?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure will set the same machinekey on all of your instances during startup, unless you have explicitly set your own machinekey in web.config.

Comment: I did explicitly set a machine key in the web.config for forms authentication. I've now tested the above scenario with 2 web roles and the cookie persists across both machines. I still have a small doubt but will update my question when I'm 100% sure.